# Switch Statement - Type 'number' is not comparable to type 'string'

Tags: typescript

I seem to be having an issue trying to figure out how to get this working - I continue to get this error when trying to pass a string and detect whether the string has a specific operator and if so run the action using a switch statement - is there a better way for me to search for an operator in a string using a switch statement?

See Error:
[image: Error]

My Typescript function:

```
function getAns(){

    var FinalSum = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('input')).value

    switch(FinalSum){
        case FinalSum.indexOf("%"):     //Type 'number' is not comparable to type 'string'.
           try{
            getPercent();
           }catch(Error){
            InvalidEntry()
           }

           break;
        case FinalSum.indexOf("^"):   //Type 'number' is not comparable to type 'string'.
           try{
            getPercent();
           }catch(Error){
            InvalidEntry()
           }

           break;
        default:
           try{
                 var inputSum = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('input'))
                 var ans = eval(inputSum.value);
                (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('answer')).value = ans;
                (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('input')).placeholder = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('input')).value;
                (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('input')).value = "";
           }catch(Error){
                InvalidEntry();
           }  
           break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not how a switch statement works in javascript/typescript (see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). A switch checks each case for strict equality with the switch expression. But since `FinalSum` will never equal the return type of `indexOf` TypeScript complains rightfully. - You want if statements here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`switch (FinalSum) {` will mean that each case is compared against `finalSum`. If the case expression is `===` to `finalSum`, the case will be fulfilled.

But `indexOf` returns a number. So

```
switch (FinalSum) {
    case FinalSum.indexOf("%"):
```

fails:

```
switch (someString) {
    case someNumber:
```

will never be fulfilled, because a string is never `===` to a number.

`switch` is error-prone and verbose anyway. Consider using `if`/`else` instead, and combine the `%` and `^`s into one::

```
var finalSum = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('input')).value
if (finalSum.includes('%') || finalSum.includes('^')) {
    try {
        getPercent();
    } catch (Error) {
        InvalidEntry()
    }
} else {
    try {
        var inputSum = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('input'))
        var ans = eval(inputSum.value);
        (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('answer')).value = ans;
        (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('input')).placeholder = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('input')).value;
        (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('input')).value = "";
    } catch (Error) {
        InvalidEntry();
    }
}
```

It would probably also be a good idea to change `getPercent` to return a value indicating success or failure, rather than throwing. (Throwing is inelegant and requires unwrapping the whole call stack).

Also note that instead of type assertion, you might use `querySelector` and its type parameter, I think it's significantly more elegant. Eg

```
var finalSum = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('input')).value
```

could be replaced with

```
var finalSum = document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>('#input')!.value;
```